# How can I use an external library that uses "impure" CSS in my Next.js app?

Tags: css, next.js

I want to include a component library in my Next.js project but the library includes "impure" CSS. For example, it uses CSS custom properties on the `:root` element.

```
:root {
  --some-var: 20px;
}
```

Next throws this error:

> Syntax error: Selector ":root" is not pure (pure selectors must contain at least one local class or id)

How can I remove or bypass this requirement for this external library?

Comment: Have you tried adding it to `styles/globals.css`?

Comment: The impure CSS lives in the external component library, so I can't move it.

Comment: did you find any solution or workaround?